# Call to Google API from Azure: "Access is denied"

Tags: c#, azure, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to create a chatbot that can manage the Google Calendar and access to Google People. I developed the code and it works perfectly offline. The problem arises when trying to upload everything online.

The code is in C #, developed above the template provided by Microsoft. When you load the code on Azure the functionality of LUIS works, the problem arises when you make a call to the Google APIs. The bug that appears is the following:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. —>
>   System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied at
>   System.Net.HttpListener.SetupV2Config() at
>   System.Net.HttpListener.Start() at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.StartListener() at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.d__14.MoveNext()
>   — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   — at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.d__8.MoveNext()
>   — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   — at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__4.MoveNext()
>   — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   — at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__1.MoveNext()
>   — End of inner exception stack trace — at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Sample.LuisBot.Dialogs.LinkContact.ConnectPeople() at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Sample.LuisBot.Dialogs.LinkContact.GetUserName() —>
>   (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.HttpListenerException (0x80004005):
>   Access is denied at System.Net.HttpListener.SetupV2Config() at
>   System.Net.HttpListener.Start() at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.StartListener() at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.d__14.MoveNext()
>   — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   — at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.d__8.MoveNext()
>   — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   — at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__4.MoveNext()
>   — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   — at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__1.MoveNext()<—

Looking online I found many cases of similar problems, unfortunately, very few have been answered and among the few answers, none has solved the problem. Does anyone have any ideas?

One of the last points on which I focused is linked to this report https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/908, where at some point it says:

> "Sounds like its trying to launch the browser on the server and not on
>   the users browser. It works on localhost because you have the power to
>   launch a new browser session on your local pic. The problem comes when
>   you try and deploy it and it trys to launch browser on the server
>   rather in a new client browser. You should be following this authweb
>   apps https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc"

I do not know if it could be the problem. I tried to follow the link but I could not integrate the directions with my code.

Here is my autentication code:

```
  private static PeopleServiceService ConnectPeople()
    {
        // Create OAuth credential.
     CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;
        IDataStore credentialPersistanceStore   = new Dialogs.myDataStore();

        Task<UserCredential> result = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
          new ClientSecrets
          {
              ClientId = "*id*",
              ClientSecret = "*secret*"
          },
          new[] { "profile", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly" },
        "me",token,
          credentialPersistanceStore);

        result.Wait();
        UserCredential credential = result.Result;

        // Create the service.
        var service = new PeopleServiceService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "*nome*",
        });

        return service;
    }
```

Then I use "service" to work with Google API.

I have worked following:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet
and https://dev.botframework.com/.

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial you are following [.NET Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet) is designed for use with a .NET console application.  It works becouse it spawns the web browser for authentication on your local machine.    When you try to deploy it to a web server it wont work because you cant spawn a browser on the web server you need to spawn it on the users machine.

You should be following this for authentication [Web applications (ASP.NET MVC)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc)

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

namespace Google.Apis.Sample.MVC4
{
    public class AppFlowMetadata : FlowMetadata
    {
        private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = "PUT_CLIENT_ID_HERE",
                        ClientSecret = "PUT_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE"
                    },
                    Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                    DataStore = new FileDataStore("Drive.Api.Auth.Store")
                });

        public override string GetUserId(Controller controller)
        {
            // In this sample we use the session to store the user identifiers.
            // That's not the best practice, because you should have a logic to identify
            // a user. You might want to use "OpenID Connect".
            // You can read more about the protocol in the following link:
            // https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login.
            var user = controller.Session["user"];
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = Guid.NewGuid();
                controller.Session["user"] = user;
            }
            return user.ToString();

        }

        public override IAuthorizationCodeFlow Flow
        {
            get { return flow; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any example that uses this code? I do not understand how to integrate it into my solution

Comment: only this https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples/tree/master/Calendar.ASP.NET.MVC5