# OAuth2 with gmail account using MailKit do not work on Azure WebJobs

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, gmail, azure-webjobs, mailkit

The code works fine on my local machine, but I get an `"Access Denied"` running it on Azure WebJobs

```
const string GMailAccount = "myaccount@gmail.com";

var clientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
{
    ClientId = "XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    ClientSecret = "XXX"
};

var codeFlow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
{
    DataStore = new FileDataStore("CredentialCacheFolder", false),
    Scopes = new[] { "https://mail.google.com/" },
    ClientSecrets = clientSecrets
});

var codeReceiver = new LocalServerCodeReceiver();
var authCode = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(codeFlow, codeReceiver);

var credential = await authCode.AuthorizeAsync(GMailAccount, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);

if (credential.Token.IsExpired(Google.Apis.Util.SystemClock.Default)) await credential.RefreshTokenAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);

var oauth2 = new MailKit.Security.SaslMechanismOAuth2(credential.UserId, credential.Token.AccessToken);

using (var mailClient = new ImapClient())
{
    await mailClient.ConnectAsync("imap.gmail.com", 993, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
    await mailClient.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);
    var inbox = mailClient.Inbox;
    inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
    var items = inbox.Fetch(0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.Size | MessageSummaryItems.Flags);
    // iterate over all of the messages and fetch them by UID

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var uid = item.UniqueId;
        var myMessage = inbox.GetMessage(uid);
        Console.WriteLine(uid);
    }
        await mailClient.DisconnectAsync(true);
}
```

Azure WebJob log :

```
exception.System.Net.HttpListenerException (5
 ): Access is denied
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.AuthorizeAsync(String userId, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)
```

Comment: You can refer to [Call to Google API from Azure: "Access is denied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48265391/call-to-google-api-from-azure-access-is-denied), [ASP.Net on Azure Apps cant redirect after Google login with new Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71235627/asp-net-on-azure-apps-cant-redirect-after-google-login-with-new-users) and [Connecting to Google Sheets through Azure Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59861396/connecting-to-google-sheets-through-azure-web-application/59861752#59861752)

Comment: [HttpListenerException - Google OAuth2 - Access is Denied](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/aspnet/en-US/41c53a93-7b45-428a-993b-259b91887c0c/httplistenerexception-google-oauth2-access-is-denied?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the code for desktop apps instead of web apps (see your call to AuthorizationInstalledApp).

That call expects to be able to spawn a desktop browser window which obviously won’t work for a web app running on a headless server.

If you are using ASP.NET, someone just recently sent me a sample to include in MailKit’s GMailOAuth2.md file.